# Restrict publishing to certain Taxonomy Terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

Greetings and salutations. I am struggling to find a solution to the following matter:

**Goal:** 
A Taxonomy named Sections has terms like *Term 1, Term 2, Term 3*. The goal is to only allow users to **publish** content under *'Term 1'* and *'Term 2'* and any content posted under *'Term 3'* **will not be automatically published** and put to the moderation queue.

**Modules tried (with no success):** 
[Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) 
[Taxonomy Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Here's how I managed to get it to work:

1) install the module 
2) activate it 
3) GO to /admin/config/workflow/rules and add a new rule 
4) set post type to my post type 
5) Added an OR condition 
6) Under that OR condition added Data Comparision to [node:field-section:tid] to my term's ids
7) in Action added unpublish content

Seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Each Term we can connect with content type by "term reference"
Each content type we controlled publish or unpublish

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I am having trouble understanding the last part of your answer. My goal is to either programmatically or using a module - automatically unpublish and hold for moderation all posts under Term 3.